# iOS device flicker

Tags: ios, ipad, flicker

After running for a few minutes my app starts to flicker in certain areas. Problem occurs on iPhones and iPads, and confirmed on multiple devices.

Video of problem:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HDE2EgWt9q8

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Looks like hardware problem and should have nothing to do with your app. Judging by flickering status bar....

Comment: I confirmed the problem on multiple devices.

Comment: Can you add more information, please? What is your app doing, especially with respect to drawing, when the flickering is happening?